# nginx www and non www to non www https

Tags: nginx, https

I want both www and non www urls to got to non www on https.

I have the following blocks in my NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that www of example.com still gets translated to www.example.com on https while I want to strip the www.

I don't really see what I am missing here...

Comment: what's the real domain, does you ssl cover both domains? what does redirect-checker.org show?

Comment: CONGRATULATION. Everything seems to be fine.

http://www.jioness.com
301 Moved Permanently
https://jioness.com/
200 OK But Chrome still keeps the www in the URL.

Comment: yup. gotta 301 it back :)

Comment: Ok I see, I added a server block on https for www as well now, it seems to work. server {
        listen 443;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

Comment: yup, the easiest way to clear a 301 is with a 301 back, code below should work too if you don't want to use SNI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to 301 back if you have an SSL that matches both domains.

**Option without SNI support**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

if ($http_host = www.example.com) {
        rewrite  (.*)  https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    ...
}
```

If not you'll need SNI, or another IP for the www record and then a temp ssl (like from Letsencrypt) to redirect your users to the correct domain.

**Option with SNI support**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

...
}
```

Comment: This works good as well, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: I would just note that POST requests won't work

Comment: A better alternative in terms of performance is to use a separate server block for `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`.